# HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize() equivalent for HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I was previously using HttpClient for making web requests, but now I want to switch to HttpURLConnection. I am doing this on Android. I am switching since it is recommended by Google android folks and there are some other reasons. (I am aware of the bug in below FROYO versions, but still want to switch)

Previously I had something like this:

```
HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(SOME_SIZE);
```

Now that I am switching, what is the equivalent of this in case of **HttpUrlConnection** ?

Do I set the size on the InputSteam reader I get from `httpURLconnection.getInputStream()` ?
like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLconnectio.getInputStream), SOME_SIZE);
```

Also, if I am using POST, do set this size on the output writer as well?